# Do apps installed on SSD run faster even if the OS is installed in HDD?

Tags: ssd, performance, benchmarking

Suppose a computer is running on an OS installed on its HDD. Now if we install other softwares on the SSD attached to the same computer instead of the HDD, will those softwares perform better than those installed on the HDD ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will but the difference could range from barely perceptible to ten-fold! This depends what type of application this is. Any application needs to be loaded from storage to memory. SSD are substantially faster than HDD and so loading time is always faster. This will make a difference proportionally to the application size. Generally though, loading is not much of a concern for most end-user software since you it's startup time.

While running, the actual bottleneck varies between software. We say a software is I/O-bound when it spends most of its time waiting for I/O. For application that need to read or write large amounts of data, SSDs really shine. Most software for video editing and processing fall into this category since they work with much more data than can fit into memory. Working with gigapixel images and large 3D models also benefits enormously from an SSD.

Other applications, those that work in memory entirely once loaded will see much less improvement since they do not require much I/O  bandwidth. It is the data that matters though. Some applications are fairly small but let you work on large files, in which case you will get a huge benefit from simply moving your data to an SSD. The application itself can remain on a standard HDD.

SSD truly brought a huge leap in performance compared to traditional HDD and so some applications really see a dramatic improvement. Very few technologies have surpassed their predecessors by so much yet this has happened again recently with NVMe. A typical SSD is 5X faster than a HDD and NVMe is 10X faster than SSD. I recently replaced my system and VM SSDs with an NVMe RAID and experienced a huge improvement.

Comment: You seem to use "disk" to refer to SSD and HDD, which is confusing. SSDs do not have any platters (aka disks).

Comment: Guess most people don't realize the D in SSD and the second D in HDD stand for disk. Let me try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an optimal environment. You will see some speed increase but I do not think it will be dramatic.

I have two machines here: one all SSD and one fast HDD. Once Windows is loaded (SSD makes that part very fast), most apps are fine on fast HDD and not dramatically faster on SSD.

SSD makes startup faster and things like virtual machines much faster. But ordinary apps benefit by some amount, but not dramatically faster on SSD.

SSD is also faster when everything (Windows, apps and data) is all on one drive.

Your machine might seem a bit smoother when picking up an app from the SSD.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the application in question and how you define "faster."  In reality, the programs themselves do not run any faster, their ability to read and write data to and from the disk is.  For example, running a game off of a SSD will allow it to launch faster.  The game might even *feel* faster, as it can load assets off the disk much quicker.  You might see models and textures for enemies show faster than you did before.  However, the program itself is still running as the speed it was before.

So in short, you computer will *feel* faster, but the only thing that has actually changed is the speed of the disk.  Dont get me wrong, it is like night and day, depending on how disk heavy your usage is.  It will also depend on how much these applications require libraries installed in the Windows installation on the mechanical HDD.  There are a lot of factors and everyone's benefit from a SSD will be unique to their hardware and usage.

Of course, the best possible thing to do is get a SSD that can hold all your data.

Comment: *"For example, running a game off of a SSD will allow it to launch faster ... load assets off the disk much quicker."* -- You use *"SSD"* and *"disk"* interchangeably, which is lame.  SSDs do not have any platters (aka disks).

Comment: @sawdust  "I use SSD and disks interchangeably."  What is the D is SSD?  I didnt know being correct is "lame"

Comment: "What is the D is SSD?" -- Same word as the *second* 'D' in HDD: Drive.  See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-vs-hdd.html and https://www.avast.com/c-what-is-ssd and https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/SSD-solid-state-drive and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive

Comment: The D in SSD is Drive whereas in HDD the first D is for disk and the second D is for Drive. So we can refer to both of them as "drive" but we can't refer to both of them as "disk".